# How to create platform independent GUI in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface

I am currently developing a java application whose GUI slightly differs with respect to OS.

The screenshots of the app in WINDOWS 7 and Redhat linux is as follows

[image]

[image]

As we can see from the pictures, the consistency of GUI elements differs. How can I make the GUI consistent?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not really an answer, but -- are you sure you want to do that? As a user, I kinda hate it when an app decides to do its own custom look and feel. It's visually jarring to have one app look different than all the others. It's one of my biggest UI gripes with IntelliJ, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a platform-consistent `look and feel` for your application.

See:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html

Nimbus is a recent one that looks decent:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html

Answer (score 1):

Making a desktop app GUI look exactly the same across OS's is a massive headache that usually isn't worth the pain. Essentially you need to make custom UI elements instead of using the defaults because the defaults leave some of the look up to the OS. (There are some libraries to help out with this.)

Comment: Check out the pictures down the SWT page (http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) to see the kind of variation that is expected in most apps.

Answer (score 1):

I think the default lookandfeel manager on windows and linux differ. You have to find out if there is a common lookandfeel manager on both platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own gui controls and draw them like images. Keep in mind that it will take longer to make everything work right.